# no configuration section <common/logging> found

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, common.logging

I'm using `system.diagnostic` to log all the errors to a log file

**Web.Config:**

```
<system.diagnostics>
    <trace autoflush="true" indentsize="4">
      <listeners>
        <add name="MyListener" type="System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener" initializeData="MyListenerLog.txt" />
        <remove name="Default" />
      </listeners>
    </trace>

  </system.diagnostics>
```

**Code:**

```
 private static void AddToMyListner(string message)
        {
            try
            {
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.WriteLine("Text: " +message + "," + DateTime.UtcNow);
                System.Diagnostics.Trace.Close();
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }
        }
```

In the Log file the first log i got was

```
no configuration section <common/logging> found - suppressing logging output
```

This log is printed only once i.e. only when I create a new log file. I'm not using `Common.Logging` so i was wondering what is causing this issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Common.Logging is commonly integrated with tracing.  If you're getting this error and you're not deliberately referencing Common.Logging then you're probably referencing some external library that uses Common.Logging and subscribes to the trace by default.  If there's no configuration in place (reasonable, since you're not intending to use Common.Logging) then this would happen when Common.Logging receives a notification that something was written to the trace and doesn't know what to do about it.

Comment: im using the default tracer as you can see in the web.config. M i missin something?

Comment: @NikiteshKolpe - What other libraries is your project referencing?

Comment: It turns out the reference was not properly added.. I removed the references deleted the config values and after compiling again added the references.. it worked..